# What word did the English use before 'because'?

Tags: english, historical-linguistics

Looking at the origin of the word 'because' I find it evolved from the phrase 'by cause', which was influenced by the French *par cause de* ; 'by cause' appeared in Middle English. What word was in use before, ex. in Old English?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Beowulf* mostly uses some form of "forþon" (variations: forþan, forþam, etc.), though in a couple of places (such as lines 2638 and 2641) it uses "þe."

Comment: Is that related to 'for then' or something like that?

Comment: @curiousdannii: maybe, or maybe it's related to "forth on." Dunno.

Comment: No, it's *for* "because of" plus *þon* instr. of the demonstrative pronoun *se* "that", or alternatively plus *þam* dat. of the same pronoun.

Comment: @TKR So it would be "for thon"?

Comment: @Zgialor: Yes, *þ* is an older spelling of *th*.

Comment: @TKR I'm aware of that, I was just wondering if it would have meant the same time as it did when "thon" was last in common usage.

Comment: @Zgialor: Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: @Zgialor it would just mean "for that" = "because of that".

Comment: @TKR Words can change meaning over time; this applies to "thon" as well.

Answer (score 4):

*for* is an old-fashioned-sounding synonym of "because": e.g.,

*I dared not go outside, **for** it was raining.*

But I am not sure if *for* was the direct predecessor of *because*.